# How to fix this WinRM error? (Set-WSManQuickConfig error)

Tags: windows, powershell

On Windows XP Pro SP3, when I run `Set-WSManQuickConfig` (after agreeing to the new settings), I get this error:

```
Set-WSManQuickConfig : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="5"
MCOMPXP"><f:Message>Access is denied. </f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:21
+ Set-WSManQuickConfig <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WSManQuickConfig], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.SetWSManQuickConfigCommand
```

How do you fix this error?

This URL is no help to fixing this issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/23fcf1da-8111-4549-aa69-1d58c8f1784d

Comment: This is how to solve issue: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/e1eabe4c-0796-420e-b03e-dffc71760b8d

Answer (score 1):

Here's my trouble shooting guide to fixing this problem, it covers:

- Is your machine connected to a domain or work group?
- Are you logged in as a local Administrator?
- Was PowerShell launched as 'Administrator'?
- Is your password blank?
- Are you trying to connect to a SharePoint farm?
- Is your Server hosted/managed by a Hosting company?
- Are you using VirtualBox?
- Are you running the command on a computer where the language is not
  set to English?

[https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/337905/enabling-powershell-remoting-access-is-denied/568228#568228)